# Filter Column Doesn't Display

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I'm trying to set up a basic Mvc.Jquery.Datatables runthrough. I'm getting an extra row at the top which isn't the expected filter row.

[image: Datatables with double header]

There is a script error in the background 'Uncaught TypeError: {object Object} has no method 'columnFilter' as shown below
[image: Uncaught TypeError: {object Object} has no method 'columnFilter']

My Index View is

```
@using DataTables.Controllers
@using Mvc.JQuery.Datatables
@using Mvc.JQuery.Datatables.Serialization

<script src="~/Content/DataTables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/DataTables/media/css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h2>Datatables Demo</h2>

@{
    var vm = Html.DataTableVm("table", (HomeController h) => h.GetDataObject(null), null);
    vm.ColumnFilter = true;
    vm.StateSave = true;
}

@Html.Partial("DataTable", vm)
```

My controller code is

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = DataRepository.GetData();
        return View(data);
    }

    public DataTablesResult<MyDataObject> GetDataObject(DataTablesParam dataTablesParam)
    {
        var data = DataRepository.GetData().Select(o => o).AsQueryable();
        return DataTablesResult.Create(data, dataTablesParam);
    }

}
```

How to get the sort row to show? Thanks.

---

** Solution **

As suggested, I was missing the script

```
<script src="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a missing script tag for the column filter extension. compare the references against the example page.

also make sure you are using EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider or have the templates project installed

Comment: thanks for porting jquery.tables to mvc iqueryables. its awesome